# how can i authenticate an html control in a .aspx page

Tags: c#, asp.net, html, authentication, page-lifecycle

how can i authenticate an html control in a .aspx page.

For eg. I have two labels :: lblusername and lblpassowrd, two textboxes to fetch the values from the user and a submit button.
I want all these controls to be of html controls not the asp.net server side controls, authenticate whether the password already exists, check for password string to be ok and on submit give user the home page.
any code help for this. 
would also expect some discussion on the events fired, effect on the asp.net page life cycle and some insight about the performance.

Comment: Yooo hooo, we have homework, boys!

Comment: Don't really see the point using asp .net but not using .net controls.. Is there any reason for not using the .net way of theauthentication?

Comment: hey stefane, its a mandate by the client it manager for a perticular domain, may be he likes html more than asp.net. the project is though in asp.net

Comment: hey Steve, i have not used mvc though. and its a mandate for such control in html only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once the HTML controls have the runat="server" attribute, you just use the normal ASP.NET way of authenticating and authorizing.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178329.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f8kdafb5%28VS.71%29.aspx

Comment: Hi Irish, the second web link seems to be more connected to my question. thanks, also i need more insight about the authentication, how it changes the page life cycle routine, and some comments on performance too.

Comment: Just do the checking in the PostBack block of the Page_Load. Grab password from text box and check against your stored value. You could have a separate panel with an error message if the authentication is unsuccessful.